# Cloning record - update with newer id

Tags: apex

EDIT:

this is master / child relationship records

```
Master object -  district__c
Child object - area__c
```

The store_id field is in the area__c object,
the user will have a master record but may/or may not have a child record

for an example:

1. let's say the master record does have a child record with store_id and user cloned the record.
2. when the user cloned the record, I want to compare the old store_id to make sure update those store_id with new store_id (by doing generateRandom numbers)

BEFORE CLONE the record

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Id             store_id
----------------------------------------------------------
321            23423423
321            23423423
321            23423423
456            54543345
456            54543345
567           
789
```

AFTER CLONED it looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Id             store_id
----------------------------------------------------------
321            55553423 (newly generated ids)
321            55553423 (newly generated ids)
321            55553423 (newly generated ids)
456            66663345 (newly generated ids)
456            66663345 (newly generated ids)
567           
789
```

END EDIT:

I have following scenario:

I have two ids here

1. Id, when you clone the record
2. newId after you clone the record generate a new id and updated the clone record.

so, as you can see the store_id is different with each id here.

so if the user clone this record 321 --> I want to update all those store_id with the new one, for the sake of simplicity I'm hard coding.

```
Set<string> setdbIds = new Set<String>();  
setdbIds.add('23423423'); 
setdbIds.add('54543345'); 

set<string> store_id = new set<string>();
string new_store_id = '';

for(Integer i = 0; i < dbRecords.size() ; i++){
     
    //the issue i see here everytime it will generate the new 
random number which I want to use only for the first time and 
then use the same until `store_id` is different.
    if(setdbIds[i] == dbRecords[i].store_id){
          dbRecords[i].store_id = generateRandomNumber(); //returns string of numbers.
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question several times, please correct me If I am wrong, you trying to create new clone child records store id with group rather than generating random store id for each child record.

For the simplicity, I will just focus on store id fields. Here what I would do:

First, we need to create the map between old store id and new store id before cloning records:

Using your data as example

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Id             store_id
----------------------------------------------------------
321            23423423
321            23423423
321            23423423
456            54543345
456            54543345


----------------------------------------------------------
Id             store_id
----------------------------------------------------------
321            55553423 (newly generated ids)
321            55553423 (newly generated ids)
321            55553423 (newly generated ids)
456            66663345 (newly generated ids)
456            66663345 (newly generated ids)
```

```
So we should have a map like:
----------------------------------------------------------
Old Store Id          New Store_id
----------------------------------------------------------
23423423              55553423 
54543345              66663345
```

Then in Apex class, this would be my approach:

```
Public Class ExampleClassName{
   Public void ReplacingStoreIds(List<ObjectName__c> ChildRecords){
      Set<Id> OldStoreIdSet = new Set<Id>(); 
      Map<Id,Id> OldStoreNewStoreIdMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
      for(ObjectName__c rec: ChildRecords){
          if(String.isNotBlank(rec.storeId__c )){
              OldStoreIdSet.add(rec.storeId__c );
          }
      }
      
      if(OldStoreIdSet.size() > 0){
         for(Id oldStoreIdKey: OldStoreIdSet){
              OldStoreNewStoreIdMap.put(oldStoreIdKey,generateRandomNumber());
         }
      }

      //hence we have the map between old and new store id
      //when we clone the record, we just need to populate store id field based on the map, 
      //for the simplicity, I will focus on the store id field 
      List<ObjectName__c> cloneRecs = new List<ObjectName__c>();
      for(ObjectName__c oldRec: ChildRecords){
          ObjectName__c newRec = new ObjectName__c(storeId__c = OldStoreNewStoreIdMap.get(oldRec.storeId__c));
          cloneRecs.add(newRec);
      }

      try{
         database.insert(cloneRecs,false);
      }catch(Exception e){
         //exception logic here
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: let me try and see

Comment: Updated my code a bit to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

**IF** I understand your problem correctly, which may not be the case since your example code is basically broken (you assume the `setdbIds` set is accessible like a list and you assume the number of `setdbIds` is the same as or greater than the number of `dbRecords`), all you need to do is ensure that you build up a map of "db ID" to "new store ID" during the iteration of the records:

```java
MyDBRecordType[] dbRecords = ...;

// This map tracks new store IDs generated for given Id values
Map<String, String> storeIdsById = new Map<String, String>();

// Iterate the DB records to update their store IDs. I don't know the type of
// your "dbRecords" array so have used a placeholder name
for (MyDBRecordType dbRecord : dbRecords) {
  // Try to get the new ID for this dbRecord
  //
  // Note: I don't know where your "Id" comes from since your hard coded example
  //       doesn't show it so I have assumed it is in the DB record
  String storeId = storeIdsById.get(dbRecord.Id);

  if (storeId == null) {
    // There is no mapping yet for this dbRecord to a store ID, so let's set one up
    storeId = generateRandomNumber();

    storeIdsById.put(dbRecord.Id, storeId);
  }

  // Replace the clone's store ID appropriately
  dbRecord.store_id = storeId;
}
```

Comment: updated my questions and try to make it clear, please take a look

Comment: With that update I still believe what I have suggested is more or less the answer. Does my answer not satisfy you? If so, why not?

Comment: the reason your solution does not satisfy me is because there is a flaw in your logic, so, if the `storeid is null` then i do not want to gneraterandomnumber,  second point is that i do not want to gneraterandomnumber for each child records if you look at the table it has the same randomnumber for all the ids that represents the row. I still think you have not understood what I'm asking the simplest way I try to explain is the example I gave you about before clone and after clone please read again.

Comment: I certainly do not understand what you see as a flaw here. Null is for the new store ID Lookup. The map simply ensures the same Id is mapped to the same new store ID by allocating a new store ID the first time the given Id is encountered. Have you actually looked at the mechanism I suggest and adapted it to your real code flow?

Comment: I updated the question again and this time I have added empty store_id to get an idea before and after cloned how the records look like, so I looked at your code again and I'm still not sure why you are checking the `null` and if this is null then you are generating the random_number but what I want is compare from the before cloned record and if there is store_id exists then update with the new_random_number but again this is 1:M relationship  so the key is to maintain the same random_number for all the child records, please see the table and I may not be trying to express  but table should.

Comment: The null check is there to simply know whether a new `store_id` has yet been generated for a given `Id`. I guess where I have been using the `Id` this should be the parent ID. If you can provide more detail around where you get the data from - change your sample code to reference your Apex classes or SObjects and show the relevant structure for these so I can map my code accordingly - I can improve my answer. If you could also address the points I made about your sample code so it could actually compile that would also help.